# How to change the document using pre save in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, save

I am trying to assign the pre handler to the mongoose save event and encrypt the document before saving:

```
userShecma.pre('save', function(next) {
    var self = {};
    self.Key = this.password;;
    self.EncriptedString = encrypt.encrypt(JSON.stringify(this), this.password);
    self.user = this.user
    self.decrypt = function() {
        var user = JSON.parse(encrypt.decrypt(this.EncriptedString, this.Key));
        for(var key in user) {
            this[key] = user[key];
        }
    }
    for(var key in this){
        delete this[key];
    }
    for(var key in self){
        this[key] = self[key];
    }
    console.log(this);
    next(self);
});
```

I have tried a bunch of diffrent things, sometimes I get an error, sometimes it just doesnt change the document.

Let me know if you need any more info,

 Ari

***EDIT:*** Tried Benoir's Answer, I can't edit `this`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Figured It Out:
Benoir's Answer + You Cannot add or remove properties to/from the document unless they are defined in the Schema.

Comment: you can edit properties not defines in Schema using this.getValue and this.setValue

Answer (score 3):

I believe calling `next(self)` will make the next handler think that there was an error and not save the document.

You should just call `next()`

Look at http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html
under 'Error Handling'

Comment: Not answering the Question, The Question Was How Do I edit the doc

Comment: You edit the doc by editing `this`'s attributes. I think you do that correctly, but the reason that it doesn't update is that you pass an error to `next` so it doesn't save